# ExpressJS - How to handle simultaneous requests? Requests seem to block one another.

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have the following piece of code

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');    
var http = require('http');
...
app.get('/a',function(){
  Card.findCards(function(err, result){  //Mongoose schema
    res.send(result); //Executes a query with 9000 records
  })  
});
app.get('/b', function(req, res){
  res.send("Hello World");
});
```

I find that when I make a get on localhost/a, it takes around 2.3 seconds to complete. This isn't really surprising since it fetches quite a bit of data from the database. However I find that if I GET /b while /a is loading, b will not display. It is as if the call to /a is blocking the call to /b.

Is this how express is supposed to work? I've always operated on the assumptions that individual routes are asynchronous since they take in callbacks but it seems like express can only process one request at a time. Until res.end() is called, no other request gets processed. Am I missing any configuration that I need to do?

For reference, this is how I connect to mongoose

```
mongoose.connect(dbConnectionString, {server:{poolSize:25}});
```

And this is my http server initialization part

```
http.globalAent.maxSockets = 20; // or whatever

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

EDIT: Here is the code for the Card Model and associated schema + functions

```
//Card.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CardSchema = new Schema({
  _id : {type: String},
  stores : [{
        store: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'StoreModel', required: true}
      , points: {type: Number, required: true}
  }]
});

exports.findCards = function(callback){
  var query = Card.find({}, callback); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been experiencing the same problem, with a setup similar to yours. There are two issues, both of them with the same root cause: Node has non-blocking I/O operations, but (as bbozo points out) CPU-intensive operations do block it.

The first problem lies in your mongoose call. After mongoose retrieves the documents from your collection, it converts them into mongoose objects. If you get 9000 records, it will do this 9000 times. The lines in question are in mongoose's `query.js` library; check out the for loop on its `completeMany` function to find the relevant blocking operations.

The second problem comes when Express stringifies the resulting JSON objects to send your response. The culprit is the `res.json` function under Express's `response.js` library. For a large response the blocking nature of `stringify` will be noticeable.

I am not quite sure how to solve this issue. You could probably try to use mongodb's native library, instead of mongoose. You could also try and patch Express so it uses JSON stream calls instead of the blocking stringify. Pagination of your query and response would also help, though I know it's not very simple to implement.

Comment: I agree with the above. The OP seems to do the right stuff code wise except pulling 9k records to then serialize to JSON and send 9k records out on the wire. That will never scale out regardless on how you look at it. Paginate so you can always be in control of your response times.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try :)

Afaik Node.js is not asynchronous in the general sense, it's just non-blocking in the sense if a connection is doing nothing then another connection that does something won't get blocked by the connection doing nothing,

Things that take a lot of reactor cpu time (like loading lots of data) will block the event loop, try fetching the data in smaller chunks

Comment: So mongoose db calls are blocking? I've always thought that db calls - like input - are non blocking hence the use of callbacks.

Comment: Moongoose db calls are non-blocking in the sense that your app isn't blocked by waiting for a mongo response, but your app still needs to buffer and process a couple thousand records once they arrive from mongo and that takes up CPU cycles in the reactor

Comment: That may be true, but I did a test wherein I called res.send("hello world") before the cpu consuming mongoose call. Even replaced the mongoose call with a simple sleep and the same thing still happened. Express still processed requests even while the mongoose call was happening. My conclusion therefore is that only one request/response object can be processed by express at any given time.
`app.get('/a',function(){`
  `console.log("a");`
  `res.send("a");`
  `Card.findCards(function(err, result){ `
    `console.log("done");`
  `})`  
`});`

Comment: I guess its possible that the mongo connection doesn't support parallel calls, but you'll need to get that kind of answer from someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the lean option.

Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.

Example:

```
new Query().lean() // true
new Query().lean(true)
new Query().lean(false)

Model.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
  docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

see [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)